# Circumference of a Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible that a metallic object will *not* be under the influence of a magnetic field at a certain *closeness* to a conductor, but will then experience the effect on moving to a particular distance (and onwards)? In other words, is there a threshold radius around a conductor *within* which the magnetic effect cannot be felt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object, whether it be magnetized or not (and in particular whether it be ferromagnetic or para/diamagnetic), will only experience magnetic forces when it is placed in an external magnetic field. If you are thinking of a long, straight conductor, then the magnetic field it produces will increase as you get near it (though it does decrease *inside* the conductor).

That said, there are some configurations of currents that produce a magnetic field "outside" and but none "outside". Two examples are a [toroidal solenoid](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/toroid.html), in which the field is confined to the solenoid interior and is zero in the donut hole, and two long cylindrical, [coaxial solenoids](http://www.solutioninn.com/physics/electrodynamics/magnetostatics/two-long-coaxial-solenoids-each-carry-current-i-but-in) carrying the same current in opposite directions, for which the field is confined to the middle region and cancels out in the inner region. A coaxial cable is an example of the latter.

If you are thinking about an extended distribution of currents such as a wire of nonzero thickness, then **yes**, the field is zero at the centre and it is small nearby. However, you can hardly place a metallic object *inside* a wire.